# Neo4j Desktop - offline

Tags: neo4j, installation

Is it possible to start and use the Neo4j Desktop installation on an offline network?  I get the following errors:
we're sorry, something went wrong when attempting to sign in. 
and 
Updater error:Error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

I need to do a quick demo on a private network.  Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Dave Simmons

Comment: Hi David - Could we get more information about your specific setup? Perhaps share a config file to give us more information?

Comment: I had no problem starting Neo4j Desktop (1.0.8), starting a neo4j DB (3.3.3 Enterprise), opening a local browser (via the Desktop's "Open Browser" button), and performing a query from the browser.